# Linux use CapsLock as Hyper modifier ONLY IF it is combined with other key

Tags: linux, keyboard-shortcuts

On windows, I can define custom shortcuts with CapsLocks with AutoHotKey like this:

`CapsLock & 1::Run, %chromePath%\GoogleChrome.exe`

When I press 'CapsLock' alone, it just acts like a normal CapsLock key and sets the Lock state, but when I press 'CapsLock + 1', it will not set the Lock state but run the Chrome Browser.

How can I do the same thing on Linux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution, which is inspired by [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/158765/using-xcape-xmodmap-to-change-some-keys).

To make CapsLock an extra Hyper modifier key, I can make use of [xcape](https://github.com/alols/xcape) and combine it with a properly configured ~/.Xmodmap file:

```
# move Hyper_L from mod4 to mod3
clear mod4
add mod4 = Super_L Super_R
add mod3 = Hyper_L
# configure Caps_Lock as Hyper_L 
clear lock
keycode 66 = Hyper_L 
# Ensure Caps_Lock is present in the mapping so that xcape can get and use it
keycode any = Caps_Lock
```

After running command `xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap` or re-login, make CapsLock functions as CapsLock when pressed alone, by running command `xcape -e 'Hyper_L=Caps_Lock'`.